# How do I receive a picture attached to a text without a data plan?

Tags: attachments, sms

Someone sent me a text message with a picture attached. I've got a Nokia 710 without a data plan.

Is there any way for me to see or somehow get the picture?

Comment: If it is an MMS then your carrier normally lets you view a certain amount for free (or a small fee) without an explicit data plan. They also usually provide a web page where you can view the MMS online such as http://www.o2.co.uk/myo2/picturemessages

Comment: Just curious, which provider lets you use a smartphone without a data plan?

Comment: Rogers in Canada let me upgrade for $0 and keep the plan I had. They had 4 phones that were eligible, and the Nokia 710 was the only windows phone of the 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its an MMS, then there will be a link to it. In case you want to see the image, visit the link.

**NOTE**:- Data charges will occur if you haven't got any plan activated. The charges won't be that much